# Как сделать слайдер OWL Carousel с контентом?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Нужно чтобы к каждому слайду был привязан свой контент.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На скрине показан блок, можно посмотреть его на сайте, залил сюда [ravtest1.site88.net](http://ravtest1.site88.net) .
Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var owl = $('.owl-carousel');

owl.owlCarousel({
  items: 1,
  loop: true,
  margin: 10,
  nav: false,
  dots: true
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.owl-carousel .item {
  background: #4DC7A0;
  font-size: 0;
}

.b-slider-item {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.b-slider-item:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<div class="owl-carousel">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="b-slider-item">Img</div>
    <div class="b-slider-item">Content</div>
  </div>
 <div class="item">
    <div class="b-slider-item">Img 2</div>
    <div class="b-slider-item">Content 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="b-slider-item">Img 3</div>
    <div class="b-slider-item">Content 3</div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе, добрый человек.